# Ignite servers go down if put large data into cluster

Tags: ignite

I deployed an ignite cluster in yarn. The cluster has 5 servers. Each server has 10GB memory and 8GB heap. I was trying to write a lot of data to ignite cache. Each item is an integer array whose length is 100K. The backups is 2. When I write 3980 items to the ignite cache, the cluster's heap is almost full. But instead of reject writing, the servers went down one by one.

My questions are:

1. Is there a configuration or way to control the cache ratio of servers, so the heap won't be full and servers won't go down?
2. Apparently, servers go down when write too much into cache seems not good for users. I'm wondering why ignite will let this happen, if user uses default configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Ignite, as well as Java Virtual Machine, is NOT responsible for managing or controlling a size of data sets that are placed into Java heap. This is the reason why `OutOfMemoryError` is presented in Java API because it's a responsibility of an application to handle its data sets and make sure that they fit into the heap.

1. You can set up [eviction policy](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/evictions) and Ignite may either move data to [off-heap](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/off-heap-memory) region or [swap](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/off-heap-memory#swap-space) or completely remove from the memory.
2. Refer to my foreword above. This is the responsibility of an application. Ignite can assist here wit its eviction policy, off-heap mode and ability to scale out.

Comment: It's very helpful. Thanks very much